# Using ms-graph 'Sites.Selected' permission to read role-assignments on Sharepoint document libraries

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sites

I am building an app which needs to be able to read role-assignments from document libraries on a specific Sharepoint site with the help of ms-graph. The [Sites.Selected](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/) API permission works almost perfectly for my use case but for some reason I can't retrieve all role-assignments on document libraries without *Sites.FullControl.All*. I can still retrieve roles from folders and files below a document library.

With the code below I am able to see that 'James Doe' has 'write' permissions to a library while *Sites.FullControl.All* is active for my app registration and without it the *roles* attribute holds no elements

```cs
var docLibs = await graphServiceClient.Sites[this.siteId].Drives
    .Request().GetAsync();

foreach (var docLib in docLibs){
    var perms = await graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Drives[$"{docLib.Id}"]
         .Root.Permissions.Request().GetAsync(); 

    foreach (var perm in perms) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{perm.GrantedTo.User.DisplayName} - {Perm.Roles.ToList().Count}");
    }
}

// With Sites.Selected (using ['write'] permission):
//  ==> James Doe - 0

// With Sites.FullControl.All:
//  ==> James Doe - 1
```

[image]

[image]

I've tried many other API permission but only *Sites.FullControl.All* seem to enable the reading of role-assignments correctly. I am looking for a less privileged alternative that still enables the reading of role-assignments on document libraries.

The best solution would be if [Sites.Selected](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/) could accept a request akin to

```json
// POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<...>/permissions
{
    "roles": [
        "sp.full control" // Instead of 'write' 
    ],
    "grantedToIdentities": [
        {
            "application": {
                "id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                "displayName": "My graph App"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

giving the application *FullControl* only to the specific site. However, I have not seen anyone being able to use roles besides *read* and *write* for the endpoint.

Comment: Have you checked on [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) if someone else had posted a similar issue to yours? also, (*I have no evidence, though*), but, I think this is a matter of SharePoint configuration settings - with roles and elevated permissons - not neccesary code-related. Hope it helps

Comment: Ye maybe its more related to SP than MS-graph but in that case I should probably close this issue and repost it there (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)